# Ansible demands installing MySQL-python despite it was already installed

Tags: macos, ansible, mysql-python

I am trying to create a new MySQL database with Ansible controller running on Mac OSX. When I first got `msg: the python mysqldb module is required` error message, I added a task to install the `MySQL-python` with `pip`. It got installed correctly, however still I am still getting an error from Ansible demanding its installation.

My minimal playbook is:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Ensure MySQL-python module is installed
    pip:
      name: MySQL-python
      executalbe: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pip

  - name: Create test_db MySQL database
    mysql_db:
      name: test_db
      state: present
```

when I run the playbook with:

```
ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local mysql-test.yml
```

I get the following result (with `changed` for the first task upon first run):

```
TASK: [Ensure MySQL-python module is installed] **************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [Create test_db MySQL database] *********************************************
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true}
msg: the python mysqldb module is required
```

`pip show MySQL-python` shows the package got installed correctly.

I am running Python 2.7.10 and Ansible 1.9.4 both installed with `homebrew`, thus I don't use `sudo`.

What is missing?

---

- I checked the playbook against `ubuntu/trusty64` Vagrant machine and it worked with **no problem** (with OSX being the Ansible controller, the only difference was a requirement for `sudo` in `pip` module).
- I checked the playbook on a second Mac both locally with `-c local` and remotely via SSH and got the same **error** as in original question (for `pip` to work correctly through SSH I had to add `executalbe=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pip` otherwise it reported `msg: Failed to find required executable pip`)

The results of the task when run with `-c local -vvvv`:

```
<localhost> REMOTE_MODULE mysql_db name=test_db state=present
<localhost> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1446497958.1-90296161052037 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1446497958.1-90296161052037 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1446497958.1-90296161052037']
<localhost> PUT /var/folders/nw/2vnhg_gj77v_cyfv0p1vdfj80000gn/T/tmpK3DT_j TO /Users/techraf/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1446497958.1-90296161052037/mysql_db
<localhost> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', u'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /Users/techraf/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1446497958.1-90296161052037/mysql_db; rm -rf /Users/techraf/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1446497958.1-90296161052037/ >/dev/null 2>&1']
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true}
msg: the python mysqldb module is required
```

Comment: What do you get if you invoke python manually and then do the following?
`>>> import MySQLdb`
`>>> print MySQLdb.__file__`
This should return the path to where the module is installed.  This will verify that python is finding the module properly.

Comment: @BruceP I got `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.pyc`. The file is there, permissions seem to be ok.

Comment: How did you install pip / python ? `which pip` should give you a hint, I guess MySQL-python must be installed via the same package manager than pip. `brew` would be a wild guess (on Ubuntu, it must be installed with apt, as a parallel)

Comment: @tchap I installed python via homebrew (no need to guess, I wrote it in the original question) `/usr/local/bin/pip@ -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pip`; then I used the included playbook to install mysql-python, which should (?) be performed using the default pip, which points to the above-mentioned executable.

Comment: Try to run your playbook with a very verbose settings `-vvvv` and give us the output, maybe we will have more info. BTW, why do you use `-c local` ? Could you drop it and see if that works better ?

Comment: @tchap I added the results of `-vvvv` to the question. I've always used `-c local` for local connections, is it wrong? Without `-c local` I get `msg: Failed to find required executable pip` on the first task.

Comment: I've never used it with local connection but I have a different setup so I guess it's the right way to use it. Last thing I'm thinking of is a rights problem on the directory of the MySQL installation or the "Homebrew El Capitan problem" if ever you have this OSX release (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason for the problem was that Ansible used the default OSX's Python (`/usr/bin/python`) which is visible in the results when run with `-vvvv` option.

First task succeeded because default OSX's Python called Homebrew's `pip` executable and installed the `MySQL-python` module for the Homebrew's Python.

The second task failed because it run default OSX's Python again which required `MySQL-python`, but the module was not installed for this version.

The solution was to use the option to specify the path to the Python interpreter to be used by Ansible:

```
ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local --extra-vars "ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python" mysql-test.yml
```

or to add `ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python` to the inventory file.

The same problem was [mentioned](https://serverfault.com/questions/567887/how-to-install-python-packages-to-homebrew-ansibles-site-packages-folder), it contains  answers with other possible solutions.