# Ansible requires python-apt but it's already installed

Tags: python, ansible

> **Prologue**: I am just moving first stesp in ansible, so please be patient
>
> Also: I read the answers at ['Ansible demands installing MySQL-python despite it was already installed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458889/ansible-demands-installing-mysql-python-despite-it-was-already-installed) but my case is different because locally, on the control machine, is all perfect; thanks to this question I discovered that my problem was in the remote controlled machine. So *my questions is the same but the question linked do not contains an answer to resolve my problem*.

I'm testing ansible from command line. For example, I succesfully can ping

```
~/.ssh$ ansible openvpn -C -m "ping"
192.168.1.225 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

I tried to launch an `apt update`.

> I am not sure if this is the right syntax for having the equivalent of `apt-get update`, but this *is not* the question
>
> I am using `-C` to see what ansible says to me when I ask to do a dry run.

```
$ ansible openvpn -C -m "apt update-cache=yes"
192.168.1.225 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "python-apt must be installed to use check mode. If run normally this module can auto-install it."
}
```

**EDIT** : As @Davide Maze suggested, it could be due to missing `python-apt`. So I checked, but _I have `python-apt`

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.15rc1

$ pip list
... cut ...
python-apt (1.6.2)
... cut ...

$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

My question is: **why does ansible tell me that python-apt is not installed, and how to fix this?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Thanks to @David Maze for pointing me to the right direction*

I was checking for `python-apt` in the *controller* machine, not in the *controlled* machine.

So I installed the package from the *controller* into the *controlled* machine using:

```
$ ansible openvpn -m "apt name=python-apt state=latest" --become-user realtebo
```

You can also use the following form, that does `sudo apt-get update` and wait for operator to enter the password. The user is the one logged in via ssh; so check your config. In my case, I'm using ssh keys; password login is disabled at all.

```
$ ansible openvpn -m apt -a "update-cache=yes" --become --ask-become-pass
```

> Tip 1: To avoid this interaction is available the vault, but I've not tried it yet.
>
> Tip 2: Also, `--ask-become-pass` is not in the doc where you're probably looking for, at letter `a`; this is because the option is shortened in `-K`, uppercase, so look more down [See the doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/cli/ansible.html?#cmdoption-ansible-k)

After ensuring that remotely the package `python-apt` is available, then the `-C` option started to work, exactly  because now `python-apt` is available remotely.

```
ansible openvpn -C -m "apt name=python state=latest"

192.168.1.225 | SUCCESS => {
    "cache_update_time": 1533077635,
    "cache_updated": false,
    "changed": false
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I solved this error by using **`ansible_python_interpreter`** argument while running the `ansible-playbook`, like below.

`ansible-playbook playbook_name.yml -e ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python --check`

Comment: And you if you have Python 2 and Python 3 installed with `/usr/bin/python` linked to `/usr/bin/python2`... As well as the package `python3-apt` installed... You'd specify: `-e ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: It can also be a problem if you have two versions for python3 installed. You should either uninstall one of them or specify the right one as `ansible_python_interpreter`.