# Ansible - install python3-apt package

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, ubuntu-18.04

Using `Ubuntu 18.04`, `Ansible 2.9, Python 3.6.9`, have installed `python3-apt`

On a basic ansible command `ansible -b all -m apt -a "name=apache2 state=latest"`
Get Error:

```
FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Could not import python modules: apt, apt_pkg. Please install python3-apt package."
}
```

`$ sudo apt-get install python3-apt`

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.9.12  
python version = 3.6.9

$ python --version
Python 3.7.6
```

Comment: Dependencies (like `python3-apt`) must be installed on the remote hosts you are targeting with your playbook, not on the local host where ansible is running.

Comment: @larsks - I did not know about this dependency on target machine, tried it - Did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible requires python-apt but it's already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51622712/ansible-requires-python-apt-but-its-already-installed)

Comment: @toydarian - not really. I installed `python3-apt` on the controlled/node machine also - but still same error.

Comment: I resolved this by adding :
vars:
  ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/bin/python3"  
This then looks for the python3-apt library in the correct python path

Comment: adding `ansible_python_interpreter="/usr/bin/python3"` (for example to inventory file) is the correct way to set up variable.

Answer (score 18):

Go to python3 dist-package directory

`cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`

And then link these two files

```
sudo ln -s apt_inst.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_inst.so
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

Comment: you safe few hours of my life...appreciate

Comment: if you custom install python3.9 where would the dist-packages folder be ?

Comment: It would be located in the custom folder that you have prefined before your installation.

Just in case use this command to find yours: 
```python3.9 -m site```

Comment: My target machine did not have the above two .so files. 

I solved this problem today using this command on the target machine (Debian 10):

  `sudo apt install software-properties-common gpg python3 -y`

That created the missing files that Saravit posted above.

Ansible started working once those two files were created.

Comment: Good tip!  I have python 3.9.5 in order to install ansible 2.14.0 and had `apt_inst.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, et al, so I just set up the links to those.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I had two versions of `python3` installed - `python3.7` and `python3.9`. After uninstalling the older version the problem went away.

Comment: how did you uninstalled older version ? Even after uninstalling python3.5 I am still able to use python3.5 but retrying again it says python3.5 has been removed. I used `apt remove python3.5` and `apt purge python3.5`

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/bin/python` on the remote node is probably *python 2.x* version rather than *python3*. As pointed by *@Chuck* above, changing the interpreter to *python3* should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

on my managed host, i made some debugging, i had python2 and python3.9 installed
but in /usr/bin/ i had a symbolic link

```
python -> python2
```

after removing this link and creating a new link

```
ln -s python3 python
```

and calling ansible from the managing device, it works but it still gives the warning, it seems that ansible does not like to see the python binary, but it wants to see python3 only

[image: Ansible does not like to see python but python3]